# How to get image of FontAwesomeKit using name

Tags: ios, objective-c, font-awesome

I am using [FontAwesomeKit](https://github.com/PrideChung/FontAwesomeKit), great tool for iOS to get icons from font awesome. however, the list to call there is pre-define.

For example, I want to get plane icon, I would need to call :

```
[FAKFontAwesome planeIconWithSize:20];
```

However, I want to be able to call using name as well. to call using :

```
[FAKFontAwesome getIconWithName:@"fa-plane"];
```

How to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

The `FAKFontAwesome` object inherits from `FAKIcon` which exposes the following method: `+ (instancetype)iconWithCode:(NSString *)code size:(CGFloat)size;`.

This does not use the code/name the same way you would with the CSS lib. But rather expects the unicode sequence to be passed in. So for 'fa-plane' this would be:

```
[FAKFontAwesome iconWithCode:@"\uf072" size:20.];
```

Having to use the unicode sequence is rather inconvenient, I guess that's why they created the long list of methods.

**EDIT**:

Just thought of a second way. You could use `NSSelectorFromString()` to dynamically build the method call.

Example:

```
SEL theSelector = NSSelectorFromString([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@IconWithSize:", @"plane"]);
NSInvocation *anInvocation = [NSInvocation
            invocationWithMethodSignature:
            [FAKFontAwesome methodSignatureForSelector:theSelector]];

[anInvocation setSelector:theSelector];
[anInvocation setTarget:[FAKFontAwesome class]];
CGFloat size = 20;

[anInvocation setArgument:&size atIndex:2];


FAKFontAwesome* faIcon = nil;
[anInvocation invoke];

[anInvocation getReturnValue:&faIcon];


// Use faIcon here.
```

Comment: Yes, I have tried it before I posted here, but another problem arises, since the code "\uf072" retrieve from plist file, somehow, it can't loosely put inside the method. I have tried using NSLog(@"\uf072") => '', it return as a symbol, but when I tried NSLog(@"%@",stringFromPlist) => '\uf072', it return exactly as the code. hence, I can't simply use the code, if either problem can be fixed, I would be happy, but initial problem was to use the name instead, so I asked that. I will give it a try your second suggestion

Comment: your second suggestion return me crash. not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

I submitted an issue to developer on this, and apparently someone already done it and solved on previous issue (I didn't see that). here's how you accomplish that (tested).

```
NSString *iconName = @"globe";

NSMutableDictionary *allIcons = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:[FAKFontAwesome allIcons]];

for (NSString *key in [allIcons allKeys]) {
    allIcons[allIcons[key]] = key;
    [allIcons removeObjectForKey:key];
}

NSString *resultCode = [allIcons objectForKey:iconName];
FAKFontAwesome *icon = [FAKFontAwesome iconWithCode:resultCode size:TAB_ICON_SIZE];
```

Refer : https://github.com/PrideChung/FontAwesomeKit/issues/37